# Good forms helpers for Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, forms, sinatra

I am starting to do forms and am looking for form helpers in Sinatra.

- Sinatra doesn't seem to have built-in forms helpers.
- The helpers in Padrino look like what I'm after but I don't feel up to porting my app to another framework. Plus it's starting to look like a Rails application.
- I haven't found any Sinatra forms helpers out there that are the 'de facto' choice.

Ideally, I'm after just a set of decent forms helpers that I can include as a gem and just start using, in place of hand-rolling all the base level erb/haml/ruby forms building.

What are your recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find `sinatra-formhelpers` useful and used it in some projects. Have a look at [their Github page](https://github.com/nateware/sinatra-formhelpers), the code is pretty straightforward and might just be what you are looking for. Even if not, you could add your own specialized helpers easily. You can simply install it with

```
gem install sinatra-formhelpers
```

and use it by requiring the Gem:

```
require 'sinatra/form_helpers'
```

or, if you subclass `Sinatra::Base`, by additionally including the helpers:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  helpers Sinatra::FormHelpers
  # ...
end
```

After all, part of Sinatra's philosophy is to be as light as possible. So if you want all the fancy things built in, Sinatra might just not be the right tool.

Comment: So I pushed a fix for this to persist select values across form submissions and the push was accepted but the gem was not updated. I would recommend looking for another option as it seems to be abandoned.

Comment: I got annoyed enough that I just forked it to [sinatra-formhelpers-ng](https://github.com/cymen/sinatra-formhelpers-ng) so consider using that instead (it properly persists SELECT states across form submissions).

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using `sinatra-formhelpers-ng` because it fixes a bug in `sinatra-formhelpers`.

I too found `sinatra-formhelpers` useful but it didn't appear to be maintained and I ran into a bug: the state of SELECT tags is not persisted across form submissions. So in other words, if I make a form with a bunch of fields and two dropdown lists (SELECT tags), all the fields are persisted if I say want to rerender the form in the POST due to failing validation except the SELECT tags. I fixed this and pushed it to the original `sinatra-formhelpers` repo. The push was accepted but the gem was not updated. I waited a couple weeks and then forked it to `sinatra-formhelpers-ng`.