# Equivalent erb code for html tags

Tags: ruby

I have a basic HTML code like

```
    <p>
        <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>


        <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" />

    </p>
```

Can anyone suggest me any equivalent erb code?

Hope, someone will surely help me....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your question. You can just use HTML code in a  `.html.erb` file. What do you want to do?

Comment: Are you using Ruby on Rails, or just normal Erb?

Answer (score 1):

Erb quivalent code :

```
<p>
  <%= label_tag(:first_name, "First Name") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:first_name) %>
</p>
```

Hope it will help you.
In addition to this, other rails form helpers could be [found here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).

Comment: where can I define id="firstname" in the above erb code? pls let me know..

Comment: Is this Rails specific or an erb feature?

Comment: @user3074285: Well I missunderstood your question. It is Rails specific. It can't be possible in Erb. Basically, what you want is only possible in Rails as Rails provide in-build helpers to convert/render label_tag to label or text_field_tag to input.

Comment: However, if you are working in Sinatra and Erb as template, then   sinatra-form-helpers(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207161/good-forms-helpers-for-sinatra) can help you what you want to achieve.